# How to save a file to iOS' Library/NoCloud folder?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using Cordova to develop a app that should download files using Phonegap's plugin-contentsync (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync).

I'm able to download files to my device, but I need my files to be downloaded to the /Library/NoCloud folder.

In my `config.xml`, I set the following:

`<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />`

I also saw something weird in my console when I started the download. First it references to the `NoCloud` folder, but after the download, it seems to store my files in the `Library` folder...

Here's my Xcode console:

`2016-04-19 11:37:35.284 Cravt B2B[581:609454] appPath file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4676843-6E27-48DF-B1AC-5459C3383649/Library/NoCloud/image-3177
2016-04-19 11:37:35.310 Cravt B2B[581:609498] WARNING: Trusting host s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
2016-04-19 11:37:35.311 Cravt B2B[581:609498] startDownload from https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cravt-ecommerce/production/spree/images/3177/large/890012.png?1441333372
2016-04-19 11:37:35.621 Cravt B2B[581:609498] Received challenge for host s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
2016-04-19 11:37:36.754 Cravt B2B[581:609492] Moving /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4676843-6E27-48DF-B1AC-5459C3383649/Library/890012.png to /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4676843-6E27-48DF-B1AC-5459C3383649/Library/image-3177
2016-04-19 11:37:36.809 Cravt B2B[581:609492] Error copying. File might already exist Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“890012.png” couldn’t be moved to “Library” because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4676843-6E27-48DF-B1AC-5459C3383649/Library/890012.png, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4676843-6E27-48DF-B1AC-5459C3383649/Library/image-3177, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4676843-6E27-48DF-B1AC-5459C3383649/Library/890012.png, NSUnderlyingError=0x13d6aef20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}
2016-04-19 11:37:36.812 Cravt B2B[581:609492] Task: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4676843-6E27-48DF-B1AC-5459C3383649/Library/image-3177 completed successfully`

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code to investigate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the cordova-plugin-file instead of the phonegap-plugin-contentsync since the former writes files to NoCloud.